# Web Service Connector with two-way SSL enabled

Tags: authentication, ssl

In our java application we use Web Service Connector framework (WSC) to communicate with Salesforce (https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc).
We successfuly connected with one-way authentication (server-only auth).
However we need to implement two-way SSL with mutual authentication enabled, so that our application as a client to Salesforce must provide client certificate for successful handshake.
Could anyone advise how to extend SSL parameters ins WSC required for client authentication on Salesforce side like keystore, certificate alias etc.
All needed actions on Salesforce side are carried out (user permissions, Mutual Authentication feature etc).

Timofey